# is the type of System.out.println functional interface?

Tags: java, method-reference

I do not understand one thing, should not the type of the method reference be a functional interface? So how do we pass System.out::println as a parameter to forEach?in the following code :

1-is System.out::println a Consumer?

2-if yes what is its generic type? I do not mean the type of list that is calling the method, but the generic type of the method reference that passed to the forEach.

```
Consumer<Integer> consumer=System.out::println;
numbers.forEach(consumer);
```

Comment: The type of `consumer` is `Consumer<Integer>` (a functional interface indeed, as you expect), not `System` or `System.out`. You need to read on how method references work: It's not the referenced method that belongs to the functional interface (although it can), but the target type that determines which functional interface is applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of code:

```
Consumer<Integer> consumer=System.out::println;
```

is equal to this lambda expression:

```
Consumer<Integer> consumer=i->System.out.println(i);
```

and above code block could be written in this way as an anonymous inner class using Consumer interface:

```
Consumer<Integer> consumer=new Consumer<Integer>(){
   public void accept(Integer i){
      System.out.println(i);
   }
}
```

So "System.out.println" itself it is not a functional interface, but when you use :: you implicitly implement the Consumer interface.

Answer (score 4):

The type of `System.out.println` is not a functional interface, since `System.out.println` is a method, not an interface.

However, the method reference `System.out::println` can be used as an implementation of a functional interface. Since `println` accepts an argument and returns nothing, you can say that it "consumes" the argument you pass to it. Therefore it fits as an implementation of the `Consumer<T>` functional interface.

Note the there are multiple variants of `println`, which can be used to implement different functional interfaces.

For example:

- A method reference to `public void println(int x)` can implement `IntConsumer`.
- A method reference to `public void println(double x)` can implement `DoubleConsumer`.
- A method reference to `public void println(Object x)` can implement `Consumer<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

1. System.out.println is method not an interface
2. System.out::println can be treated as an impl of interface since it takes an argument and returns nothing